# Count occurrences in a Pandas series of floats

Tags: python, pandas, counter, series

I have a DataFrame:

```
df.head()

Index                          Value
0                    1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0
1                            1.0,1.0
2                            1.0,1.0
3    3.0,3.0,3.0,3.0,3.0,3.0,4.0,4.0
4                                  4
```

I'd like to count the occurrences of values in the `Value` column:

```
Index                          Value   1    2    3    4
0                    1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0   4    0    0    0
1                            1.0,1.0   2    0    0    0
2                            1.0,1.0   2    0    0    0
3    3.0,3.0,3.0,3.0,3.0,3.0,4.0,4.0   0    0    6    2
4                                  4   0    0    0    1
```

I've done this before with string values but I used `Counter` - which I found you can't use with floats?

```
df_counts = df['Value'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(Counter(x.split(','))), 1).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Comment: Do your floats always end with `.0`? If so, you could convert the result of `.split` to integers and - if necessary - further to strings, then the count should work fine.

Comment: `df['Value'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(Counter(map(float, x.split(',')))), 1).fillna(0).astype(int)` works fine then...

Answer (score 2):

Use `map` to floats and last columns to `integers`:

```
df_counts = (df['Value'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(Counter(map(float, x.split(',')))), 1)
                        .fillna(0)
                        .astype(int)
                        .rename(columns=int))
print (df_counts)
   1  3  4
0  4  0  0
1  2  0  0
2  2  0  0
3  0  6  2
4  0  0  1
```

Last if necessary add all missing categories add [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) and [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original:

```
cols = np.arange(df_counts.columns.min(), df_counts.columns.max() + 1)
df = df.join(df_counts.reindex(columns=cols, fill_value=0))
print (df)
                                 Value  1  2  3  4
Index                                             
0                      1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0  4  0  0  0
1                              1.0,1.0  2  0  0  0
2                              1.0,1.0  2  0  0  0
3      3.0,3.0,3.0,3.0,3.0,3.0,4.0,4.0  0  0  6  2
4                                    4  0  0  0  1
```